# ASP .NET Identity add FK to AspNetUsers table

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to add a property **CilentID** to **AspNetUsers** table which is a FK to **Clients** table: (NOT ENTITY FRAMEWORK)

SQL:

[image: SQL snap]

**IdentityModels:**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [ForeignKey("Client")]
    public int ClientID { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
    [Table("Client")]
public class Client
{
    [Key]
    public int ClientID { get; set; }

    public string ClientName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'ClientID' on type 'Proj.Models.ApplicationUser' is not valid. The navigation property 'Client' was not found on the dependent type 'proj.Models.ApplicationUser'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.

What am i missing?

Comment: are the two entities in the same namespace?

Comment: yes they are...

Comment: do you have migration_history table? if yes delete it to refresh entity framework

Comment: I guess you right. i'll put link to the full guide. Thanks a lot